# Ember.js - How can I hide a partial depending on the current route?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to be able to only display a sidebar on some of my routes. How can I achieve something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="ember-app">
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            // if currentRoute == /something, then show this:
            <div class="row">
                {{partial sidebar}}
                <div class="span9 offset3 user-feed">
                    {{outlet}}    
                </div>
            </div>
            // else, show this:
            {{outlet}}
            // endif
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_sidebar">
    // Sidebar code here ...
</script>
```

So when I visit /#/something I should see the sidebar, but on all other routes, I shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe the currentPath property to match the current route with Regex.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
 showSidebar: function(){
  var routes_array = ['two','four'],
    currentPath = this.get('currentPath'),
    filteredArray, showSideBar = false;

  routes_array.forEach(function(itm){
   var tab = new RegExp('^'+itm+'*');
   if(!Em.isEmpty(currentPath.match(tab)))
    showSideBar = true;
   });
  return showSideBar;
 }.property('currentPath')
});
```

[Just a simple try Here](http://jsbin.com/uxojek/22/edit)

Comment: I'm not aware of your route names and your regex matching may be according to your route names

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix may be to use the partials argument with quotes?

```
{{partial 'sidebar'}}
```